# HtmlAgilityPack - Replace Node With Another Node

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have two nodes that have inner HTML that goes something like this:

Node1:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
```

Node2:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<div><p>lots of more paragraphs here</p></div>
```

I'm trying to look up Node1 in Node2 in order to add `<!--more-->` tag (for WordPress posts) following the first two paragraphs (or whatever HTML text is supplied in Node1).

Both of the above nodes have different parents. How do I find and replace or otherwise append the `<!--more-->` tag in such case? I tried running the following code, but it errors out:

Code:

```
node2.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(node1.InnerHtml & "<!--more-->"), node1).InnerHtml
```

Error:

```
Node "

             " was not found in the collection
Parameter name: node
```

Also tried chaging `node1` in the oldChild part to `HtmlNode.CreateNode(node1.InnerHtml)` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to perform a replacement on `HtmlNode.InnerHtml` property directly:

```
node2.InnerHtml = node2.InnerHtml.Replace(
    node1.InnerHtml, 
    node1.InnerHtml + "<!--more-->"
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I had to add a couple of levels of `Trim` (to get rid of any leading spaces of line feeds), but got it going using `Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why replacing doesn't work, however there's an InsertAfter Method you can use.

```
const string html = @"<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<div><p>lots of more paragraphs here</p></div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var secondParagraph = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[2]");
// var secondParagraph = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Skip(1).First(); //or Linq
var moreNode= HtmlNode.CreateNode("<!--more-->");
doc.DocumentNode.InsertAfter(moreNode,secondParagraph );
```

Comment: Thanks, Shriek. But this only works to insert the `<!--more-->` tag after the second paragraph. Since node1 and node2 are dynamic, I have to look up a couple thousand pairs manually to check where to insert.